# Опечатка в списке "добавить комментарий для автора": Это не ответ, а комментарий к другом ссобщению

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Как воспроизвести:

1. очередь правок
2. выбрать любой ответ
3. рекомендовать удаление

Ожидаемый результат:

> Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению

Полученный результат:

> Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому **ссобщению**

Скриншот с опечаткой:

> [image: скрин]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утвердил поправленную [@vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) опечатку:

> [image: transifex]

Будет на сайте после обновления базы переводов и пересборки движка.

Comment: Теперь всё работает отлично! :)